# Destroying old callback for button and installing new one

Tags: python, button, callback, gtk, pygobject

I have two callbacks installed for the clicked signal on the done button. Is there a way to take out (not execute) one of them e.g.

```
import threading
import time
from gi.repository import Gtk, GLib

class Test():
    def __init__(self):

        win = Gtk.Window()
        win.set_title("XYZ")

        win.set_border_width(10)

        box = Gtk.VBox(spacing=10)
        win.add(box)
        done_button = Gtk.Button(label="DONE")
        done_button.connect("clicked", self.callback1)

        #remove callback ??? callback1 should not be called when button is clicked.

        done_button.connect("clicked", self.callback2)

        box.pack_end(done_button, False, False, 0)

        win.show_all()
        win.maximize()
        win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)

    def callback1(self, widget):
        print "callback1"

    def callback2(self, widget):
        print "callback2"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test = Test()
    Gtk.main()
```

What can be done to remove callback1.

Answer (score 2):

you need to get the id of the signal in order to be able to disconnect it, so change the connect to:

```
b_id = done_button.connect("clicked", self.callback1)
```

and then use the disconnect function of the GObject module:

```
GObject.signal_handler_disconnect(done_button, b_id)
```

or as suggested by elya5 (so you don't even have to import GObject):

```
done_button.disconnect(b_id)
```

Remember to import the GObject module first (not GLib)

```
from gi.repository import Gtk, GObject
```

Comment: You can achieve the same by using `done_button.disconnect(handler_id)`. Then you don't need the GObject import. `id` is also a python built-in function so you should rather stick with another name.

Answer (score 0):

see [python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io](https://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basics.html)

If you have lost the “handler_id” for some reason (for example the handlers were installed using Gtk.Builder.connect_signals()), you can still disconnect a specific callback using the function disconnect_by_func():

`widget.disconnect_by_func(callback)`